# What does the green block mean for SSL certificates? (Chrome)

Tags: ssl

Why do I see a green block with Twitter Inc in front of the SSL lock sign, but just a simple lock sign for i.e. Facebook?

What is the difference between these certificates? Or is there a different reason?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The green bar is called extended validation:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate

> An Extended Validation Certificate (EV) is an X.509 public key certificate issued according to a specific set of identity verification criteria. These criteria require extensive verification of the requesting entity's identity by the certificate authority (CA) before a certificate is issued.

It's just a "cooler" certificate :)

> Certificates issued by a CA under the EV guidelines contain a subject with x509 OIDs for jurisdictionOfIncorporationCountryName, businessCategory, and serialNumber, with the serialNumber pointing to the ID at the relevant Secretary of State (US) or national business registrar (outside US), as well as a CA-specific policy identifier so that EV-aware software, such as a web browser, can recognize them.

The main difference:

> EV certificates use the same encryption as other types of SSL certificates: the difference is in the validation process as indicated by the policy identifier in the certificate.

Comment: "It's just a "cooler" certificate" lol. Thanks for your answer. Good to know what it is called so I can look it up :)